# One who expresses (or the act of) feigned sympathy/interest in hopes of being recognized for it

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that encompasses both these ideas. I thought **pharisaic** would be a bark up the right tree, but it appears to pertain more to hypocrisy and legalism.

Ideally the word should encapsulate the idea that some form of *good* is being displayed for the primary purpose of *self-gain*.

I understand that such an action could be **hypocritical**, but that word does not necessarily imply the act of *doing good only for the praise it brings*.

*The Pharisees* are a great example of this (with their ostentatious tithing), but the word named after them doesn't seem to have been applied to that aspect of their character.

Comment: It's an open compound, but 'false friend' is simple (though it does have a linguistic sense too).

Comment: "Ideally the word should encapsulate the idea that some form of good is being displayed for the primary purpose of self-gain."--Someone who has an ULTERIOR MOTIVE/ VESTED INTERESTS then.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like:

**sanctimonious**: *hypocritically pious or devout*.  It's not exactly about "doing good", but I do feel it encapsulates the idea of being good (if in a religious manner) for show.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered **[self-serving](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-serving)**:

> serving one's own interests *often in disregard of the truth* or the interests of others

or **[sycophant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sycophant)**:

> a person who praises powerful people in order to get their approval

**[Pharisaical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pharisaical)**: marked by hypocritical censorious self-righteousness

Answer (score 1):

This kind of person is called a "**[goody-goody](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goody-goody)**".

> *adj.* Affectedly sweet, good, or virtuous.
>
> *adj. n.* **1.** a person who is self-righteously, affectedly, or cloyingly good or virtuous.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the term "crocodile tears".

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crocodile+tears

crocodile tears: a hypocritical display of sorrow; false or insincere weeping

1. The secretaries wept crocodile tears over the manager's dilemma.
2. Politicians shed crocodile tears over the plight of the unemployed.

Comment: "crocodile tears" are, I think, different from "feigned sympathy or interest", although the motivation may be similar.

Comment: How different are they exactly? From the context of the two example sentences, I think it's quite clear that the secretaries and the politicians are both feigning sympathy and interest.

Comment: @Louel *Crocodile tears* are limited to expressions of grief and sorrow, not necessarily sympathy or interest.  You can display sympathy without grief coming into the equation at all.

Comment: But isn't the word "sympathy" ultimately from a Greek term which means "to suffer together"?. When you sympathize with someone, you are, in fact, commiserating with them.

Answer (score 0):

How about the verb "to pander to sb's tastes" and the noun "a pander" or "a panderer"?

Definitions in the Collins English Dictionary Online:

verb

> 1. **(intransitive) *followed by to* to give gratification (to weaknesses or desires)**
> 2. (archaic when transitive) to act as a go-between in a sexual intrigue (for)

noun

> 1. **a person who caters for vulgar desires, esp in order to make money**
> 2. a person who procures a sexual partner for another; pimp

These words are very much about pleasing someone in order to gain an advantage at their expense. And payment is recognition of some sort.

The Cambridge Dictionary Online has:

verb

> to do or provide exactly what a person or group wants, especially when it is not acceptable, reasonable, or approved of, **usually in order to get some personal advantage**:
>
> *It's not good the way she panders to his every whim.*
>
> *Political leaders almost inevitably pander to big business.*

The Merriam-Webster Dictionary Online has:

noun

> 1
>   a)  a go-between in love intrigues
>   b)  pimp
>
> **2:  someone who caters to or exploits the weaknesses of others**

And I have just come across the pun **"a pander bear"**, on the Internet, defined as

> a candidate running for political office who shamelessly attempts to lure in votes by making patronizing and empty concessions and shows of support for particular special interests (www.urbandictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

Closest I can find is **insincere** / **insincerity**

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/feigned

Answer (score 0):

Conspicuous does a good job of conveying the sense of open, yet adds an air of suspicion to it.

So, perhaps *conspicuous attention* or *conspicuous giving* depending upon the actual application.

It is a direct contrast with conspicuous consumption which means spending money or resources out in the open for all to see. (And, adds an air of ostentatiousness to boot.)

But, I agree with Shisa if there is a religious component involved, *sanctimonious* is an excellent fit.